# Excel macro for loop not working as expected when

Tags: excel, macros

I have an excel worksheet with example data in column A like
row 1 has a
row 2 has b
row 3 has c
row 4
row 5 has d

Using my macro i want to add a new row above where ever there is data in the selected cell. As row 1 cell has data "a" macro should add a row and goto next cell.  row 4 has no data so it should skip this row check the next

i have macro below

```
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       FinalRow1 = FinalRow + FinalRow
       ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
   For i = 1 To FinalRow1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
     Else
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=2, columnOffset:=0).Activate
        'ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
    End If
Next i
```

It seems to work some times and other times it simply does not add the expectd row.

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

The FASTEST and DIRTY answer is:

```
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
FinalRow1 = FinalRow + FinalRow
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
For i = 1 To FinalRow1
If Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
  ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
Else
  Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=2, columnOffset:=0).Activate
  I = I +1 ' BECAUSE you have increased the next row number by 2
End If
Next i
```

The real problem: you have a loop with 2 running data:

- the loop varable I
- AND the actual position of ActiveCell

When you insert a row, they will not show the same data anymore.

It would be much nicer

- if you forget For loop and rely only ActiveCell.Offset position
- OR if you forget ActiveCell.Offset and rely only the For loop I variable.

Either way is OK, but you mixed - and in my answer I left this mix, just focused that loop varable I and ActiveCell.Offset should be in offset.. ;-)

Comment: Above did not work.  The code below works but need to add a loop as i never know the last cell in column with content  so to put row above it Columns("A")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=-2).Activate
End With

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in your code. But it is always better to loop from last row to first row.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim flag As Boolean
    finalrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    FinalRow1 = finalrow + finalrow
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    flag = False
    For i = 1 To FinalRow1
        If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
            flag = True
        Else
            If flag = False Then
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=2, columnOffset:=0).Activate
            Else
                flag = False
                ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

One drawback of this code is that it loops for few extra number of times when not needed, will work on it in sometime.

Comment: Strange your demo works on limited demo mode but when using with actual data simply not working.  the only thing i changed form demo was column to be M2 as in actual worksheet that is the row column i am using.  Do you think you could help

Comment: @newexceluser - Can you give more details on what exactly is not working with your actual data. If you can share your `Column M` I can help you better because everything is working fine for me even when I am using `Column M`.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back and thank you for your Help.  Data is basically the same as in my example its just text.  I have found the following solution which works with an error 91.  but it works.  I will send code and it has changed as have my requirements.